# Gulp-sass gives error after 2 or 3 saves from my editor

Tags: node.js, npm, gulp, saas

I can save two or three times on my editor and browsersync reloads. After 1 or 2 saves with same code gulp gives me this error

```
events.js:167
      throw er; // Unhandled 'error' event
      ^
Error: assets\css\main.scss
Error: File to import not found or unreadable: 2-modules/header.
        on line 10 of assets/css/main.scss
>> @import '2-modules/header';
   ^

    at options.error (C:\Users\wfjcu\Documents\GitHub\lig\node_modules\node-sass\lib\index.js:291:26)
Emitted 'error' event at:
    at DestroyableTransform.onerror (C:\Users\wfjcu\Documents\GitHub\lig\node_modules\vinyl-fs\node_modules\readable-stream\lib\_stream_readable.js:558:12)
    at DestroyableTransform.emit (events.js:182:13)
    at onwriteError (C:\Users\wfjcu\Documents\GitHub\lig\node_modules\through2\node_modules\readable-stream\lib\_stream_writable.js:356:10)
    at onwrite (C:\Users\wfjcu\Documents\GitHub\lig\node_modules\through2\node_modules\readable-stream\lib\_stream_writable.js:373:11)
    at WritableState.onwrite (C:\Users\wfjcu\Documents\GitHub\lig\node_modules\through2\node_modules\readable-stream\lib\_stream_writable.js:126:5)
    at afterTransform (C:\Users\wfjcu\Documents\GitHub\lig\node_modules\through2\node_modules\readable-stream\lib\_stream_transform.js:81:3)
    at TransformState.afterTransform (C:\Users\wfjcu\Documents\GitHub\lig\node_modules\through2\node_modules\readable-stream\lib\_stream_transform.js:58:12)
    at errorM (C:\Users\wfjcu\Documents\GitHub\lig\node_modules\gulp-sass\index.js:118:12)
    at Object.callback (C:\Users\wfjcu\Documents\GitHub\lig\node_modules\gulp-sass\index.js:127:16)
    at options.error (C:\Users\wfjcu\Documents\GitHub\lig\node_modules\node-sass\lib\index.js:294:32)
```

This is the gulpfile.js this seems to be working fine before. But when i upgraded to gulp 4 it didnt and I reverted back to gulp 3.9.1 it gives the error when saving on sublime.

```
var gulp        = require('gulp');
var browserSync = require('browser-sync');
var sass        = require('gulp-sass');
var prefix      = require('gulp-autoprefixer');
var cp          = require('child_process');
var pug         = require('gulp-pug');

var jekyll   = process.platform === 'win32' ? 'jekyll.bat' : 'jekyll';
var messages = {
    jekyllBuild: '<span style="color: grey">Running:</span> $ jekyll build'
};

/**
 * Build the Jekyll Site
 */
gulp.task('jekyll-build', function (done) {
    browserSync.notify(messages.jekyllBuild);
    return cp.spawn( jekyll , ['build'], {stdio: 'inherit'})
        .on('close', done);
});

/**
 * Rebuild Jekyll & do page reload
 */
gulp.task('jekyll-rebuild', ['jekyll-build'], function () {
    browserSync.reload();
});

/**
 * Wait for jekyll-build, then launch the Server
 */
gulp.task('browser-sync', ['sass', 'jekyll-build'], function() {
    browserSync({
        server: {
            baseDir: '_site'
        },
        notify: false
    });
});

/**
 * Compile files from _scss into both _site/css (for live injecting) and site (for future jekyll builds)
 */
gulp.task('sass', function () {
    return gulp.src('assets/css/main.scss')
        .pipe(sass({
            includePaths: ['css'],
            onError: browserSync.notify
        }))
        .pipe(prefix(['last 15 versions', '> 1%', 'ie 8', 'ie 7'], { cascade: true }))
        .pipe(gulp.dest('_site/assets/css'))
        .pipe(browserSync.reload({stream:true}))
        .pipe(gulp.dest('assets/css'));
});

/**
* Compile files from _pugfiles into _includes (for live injecting) and site (for future jekyll builds)
*/
gulp.task('pug', function(){
    return gulp.src('_pugfiles/*.pug')
    .pipe(pug())
    .pipe(gulp.dest('_includes'));
});

/**
 * Watch scss files for changes & recompile
 * Watch html/md files/pug files, run jekyll & reload BrowserSync
 */
gulp.task('watch', function () {
    gulp.watch('assets/css/**', ['sass']);
    gulp.watch(['*.html', '_layouts/*.html', '_includes/*'], ['jekyll-rebuild']);
    gulp.watch(['_pugfiles/*.pug'], ['pug']);
});

/**
 * Default task, running just `gulp` will compile the sass,
 * compile the jekyll site, launch BrowserSync & watch files.
 */
gulp.task('default', ['browser-sync', 'watch']);
```

node version 10.4.1

npm version 6.4.1

gulp CLI 3.9.1

gulp Local 3.9.1

Comment: We will need to see your gulpfile.js at least.

Comment: @Mark Updated the question, you have any idea why this is happening?